# How do we calculate the expected value of $X^{-1}$, where $X$ has geometric distribution?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X$ have a geometric distribution such that $p_{X}(x)  = \textbf{P}(X = x) = q^{x−1}p$, where $x \geq 1$. Show that $\textbf{E}(X^{-1}) =
\log(p^{1/p−1})$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

According to the properties of the expectation, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(g(X)) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}g(x)p_{X}(x)
\end{align*}

In the particular case when $g(X) = X^{-1}$, the problem reduces to determine
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(X^{-1}) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{x-1}p}{x} = p\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{x-1}}{x}
\end{align*}

Now consider the series

\begin{align*}
f(w) & = 1 + \frac{w}{2} + \frac{w^{2}}{3} + \ldots \Rightarrow F(w) = \int_{0}^{w}f(u)\mathrm{d}u = \frac{w}{1^{2}} + \frac{w^{2}}{2^{2}} + \frac{w^{3}}{3^{2}} + \ldots
\end{align*}

If I am on the right track, $\textbf{E}(X^{-1}) = pF^{\prime}(1-p)$. However, I am unable to find out the closed formula for both $f$ and $F$. Am I failing at some point? Otherwise, could someone help me out? Thanks!

**EDIT**

According to Alex's contribution, we can rewrite the given expression as
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(X^{-1}) = \frac{p}{q}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{x}}{x}
\end{align*}

Therefore, if we conveniently define
\begin{align*}
G(w) & = w + \frac{w^{2}}{2} + \frac{w^{3}}{3} + \ldots \Rightarrow G^{\prime}(w) = g(w) = 1 + w + w^{2} + \ldots = \frac{1}{1-w} \Rightarrow\\\\
G(w) & = \log(1-w) \Rightarrow \textbf{E}(X^{-1}) = \frac{p}{q}G(q) = \frac{p}{1-p}\log(1 - (1 - p)) = \frac{p}{1-p}\log(p)
\end{align*}

Am I missing something?

Comment: You have the right sort of idea. Try using $p\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{x - 1}}{x} = \frac{p}{q} \sum_{x = 1}^{\infty}  \int_{0}^{q}u^{x - 1} du = \frac{p}{q}\int_{0}^{q} \sum_{x = 1}^{\infty}  u^{x - 1} du$

Comment: You're missing a minus sign.  $E(X^{-1})=-\log(p^{1/p-1})$.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution!